# How to install xlc++ on AIX?

Tags: aix, compiler, xlc

How to install the compiler xlc++ on a AIX 4.3.3. server?

Where can I get the sources and instructions to installation?

Comment: You're ... running AIX 4.3.3 ... in 2018?!?!

Comment: Since xlC is a licensed product, I think you’d have better luck (if any) bootstrapping gcc. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Installation instructions for XLC++ compilers on IBM AIX are well docummented on [**IBM Support website**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1025914).